# How do visitors apply for a sim card in the U.S.?

Tags: usa, telephone

I am going to Washington DC in a few weeks, I want to know how can one obtain a phone sim card in the US? Can I get from the nearest store? or do I have to go to the telecom company?

Comment: This question belongs on [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/) rather than here, where incidentally it has [already been answered](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46771/444).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telecom companies have stores, in abundance. You can also buy pre-paid phones in any grocery store or gas station.

If you want a "post-paid" contract, you may need to put a deposit since you probably don't have any credit history.